# How does Stack Overflow recommend linked questions?

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between linked questions and related questions?

And how we retrieve these questions? Why are most of the linked questions very old questions such as three years ago?

Answer (score 2):

Linked questions are ones that are literally linked to in a question or in its answers (or comments). Related means they are conceptually related (similar keywords and tags).

If the linked questions for a given question are old, well, that's because people linked to old questions in that question, the answers to that question, or the comments.